# Break tag not working properly with Flex proprety in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an content editable `<div>` which is a kind of an rich text box editor. I will insert an `<br>` tag when on enter. When i tap enter or return twice i will insert two `<br>` tag. Similarly for three or four enter. My issue is that how many break tag i have inside the flex box. It respects only one line break in firefox.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div>Try reproducing this <br><br><br>in firefox<br><br></div>
```

I tried a workaround for this by adding a line of css `br + br{margin-top:10px}`. But this fails when there is multiple line break inserted. You can see that first line break and second line break will not have equal line-space.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
}
br + br{
  margin-top:10px
}
```

```html
<div>You can see the first line<br><br>and second line will not have equal space<br><br>, even thought they have same amount of line-break</div>
```

This issue appears only in firefox. My condition is i don't want to add an extra DOM wrapper inside the flex Div. And don't want flex property to be removed

Comment: So `flex` needs to be applied to the `contenteditable` element itself?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody. Yes